# Extract image features using Caffe for custom image classifier

Tags: python, computer-vision, neural-network, caffe, conv-neural-network

I would like to obtain the output of the 6th layer of a pre-built caffe model and train an SVM on top of it. My intention is to build a custom image classifier, where the user can create custom image classes, and classify input images among those classes, instead of the imagenet classes.Here is the pseudo code:

```
#input
file='cat.jpg'
image=caffe.io.load_image(file)

#model
net = caffe.Classifier('deploy.prototxt','model.caffemodel')

#compute activation at layer 6 --- Need help here. Will net.forward help? will the activation be retained? 

#extract features from layer 6:

features = net.blobs['fc6'].data[4][:,0, 0]


#SVM
category=svm.predict(features)
print get_category_name(category)
```

Comment: Then, what is the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `Net` class, instead of `Classifier`. Thus, you just need to call `net.forward()`.

Two things to pay attention to:

1. Preprocess your input image. See `Transformer` class [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/io.py) for reference.
2. If you extract the features by using just

   ```
   features = net.blobs['fc6'].data
   ```

   your array will be overwritten by the next `forward()` call. Be sure you are performing a **deep copy**, such as

   ```
   features = net.blobs['fc6'].data.copy()
   ```

Comment: why Net instead of Classifier? Classifier does all the image processing by itself right?

Comment: Simply because Classifier was provided as an example by the Caffe developers. It hides the necessary preprocessing, which can be application-dependent. In short, you should define your **own** Classifier class.